# how can I get Real IP?

Tags: php, web, ip-address, registration

I have developed a website. I used $_SERVER variable to find the IP of client. When internet connection is refreshed, it shows different IP. How can I get the real IP so that a client can register only one account from one computer?

Comment: you can't. it'll never work. do you think everyone gets static IPs these days?

Comment: Pitchinnate has it correct because users could connect via a proxy or a VPN or a tunnel and have a completely different IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to guarantee that one computer (or user) will only ever register one account. Even if the majority of your users have a fixed IP address, the people who set out to break your system will simply find ways to connect to your site via different routes so that your checks don't realise they are the same people each time.

You could design your system to require a valid email address, which will reduce the amount of tampering, but won't stop a determined person from registering several accounts on your site using disposable email addresses.

Comment: As a late update to this answer, I'll add that I currently work for a company which uses proxy services to allow it to access and register with target websites using dozens of different IP addresses. The targeted companies don't always like it much, but it is seemingly permitted under UK law. A few companies regularly wriggle and block IP addresses, but it's easy to switch to a different set of proxies and regain access almost immediately. Trying to filter by IP address will never slow down a determined client for very long.